# JAVAFX LISTVIEW REFRESH TAB

Tags: listview, javafx, controller, reload

I'm stuck in school projet.

I have javafx project, with a Controller A and Controller B.
The A controller is associated with Tab A, and B conrtoller with Tab B.

In both controller, I have a listview listing the same object (@FXML Listview moviesList for example).

In Tab A, I can remove a movie from the listview. No problem, the object is deleted from the listview.

But problem, when I switch on the Tab B, the object is still in the Listview.

And I don't know how to refresh this listview after deleting the object.

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private TabPane rootLayout;
private Tab tabMovie = new Tab("Movies");
private Tab tabRoom = new Tab("Rooms");


@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Javaravi Admin");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);

        loadScreen();

        showMovies();

        showRoomsAndShows();


    }


public void loadScreen() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("menu.fxml"));
            rootLayout = fxmlLoader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
            rootLayout.getTabs().addAll(tabMovie, tabRoom, tabParam);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


public void showMovies() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("movie.fxml"));
            AnchorPane filmView = fxmlLoader.load();

            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.

            tabMovie.setContent(filmView);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            MovieController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();


        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



public void showRoomsAndShows() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("system.fxml"));
            AnchorPane room = fxmlLoader.load();

            // Set person overview into the c enter of root layout.
            tabRoom.setContent(room);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            SystemController systemController = fxmlLoader.getController();


        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

MovieController.java

```
public class MovieController {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Film> moviesListView;

    private Database db = Database.getInstance();
    private ModelFactory mf = ModelFactory.getInstance();

    public MovieController() {
    }

    private void showAllMovies() {

        List<Film> moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Model> modelsList = mf.getAllModels("Film");
        for (int i=0; i<modelsList.size(); i++) {
            moviesList.add((Film) modelsList.get(i));
        }
        ObservableList<Film> myObservableList = FXCollections.observableList(moviesList);
        setMoviesItems(myObservableList);
    }

    private void setMoviesItems(ObservableList<Film> item) {

        moviesListView.setItems(item);
    }

@FXML
    private void initialize() {

        showAllMovies();
    }

    @FXML
    private void deleteShow() {

        Film selectedFilm = moviesListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

            System.out.println("Validation suppression");
            selectedFilm.removeFromDb();
            showAllMovies();
            moviesListView.requestFocus();
            moviesListView.getSelectionModel().select(0);
            getSelectedMovie();      

    }
```

Show.java

public class SystemController {

```
@FXML
private ListView<Film> selectedMovieResa;

@FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // initialize lists
        showAllLanguages();
        showAllShows();
        showAllMovies();
        showAllRooms();
    }

// set movies list
    private void showAllMovies() {

        // same process as the first one (line 158, set room list)
        List<Film> moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Model> modelsList = mf.getAllModels("Film");
        for (int i=0; i<modelsList.size(); i++) {
            moviesList.add((Film) modelsList.get(i));
        }
        ObservableList<Film> myObservableList = FXCollections.observableList(moviesList);
        setMoviesItems(myObservableList);
    }

    public void setMoviesItems(ObservableList<Film> item) {

        selectedMovieResa.setItems(item);
        movieFromShow.setItems(item);
        filterMovie.setItems(item);
    }
```

Tks !

Comment: Either display one `ListView`, so that it is outside of the `TabPane` (and hence always visible, no matter which tab is selected), or have both `ListView`s share the same list of items. (It's pretty much impossible to answer the question more fully without you providing an example application, i.e. an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: I edit as good as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is each of your `ListView`s contains a different `ObservableList` with the data. So removing from one list will not remove from the other. The best solution is to let both list views share a single data list.

Have your `ModelFactory` class create a (single) `ObservableList<Model>` and return it via a `getMovies()` method. Something like

```
public class ModelFactory {

    private ObservableList<Film> filmList = null ;

    // existing code...

    public ObservableList<Film> getMovies() {
        if (filmList == null) {
            List<Film> films = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Model> models = getAllModels("Film");
            for (Model m : models) {
                films.add((Film)m);
            }
            filmList = FXCollections.observableList(films);
        }
        return filmList ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you just have a single list that can be shared by the various views:

```
public class SystemController {

    // ...

    public void showAllMovies() {
        setMoviesItems(mf.getMovies());
    }

    // ...
}
```

and

```
public class MoviesController {

    // ...

    public void showAllMovies() {
        setMoviesItems(mf.getMovies());
    }

    // ...

    @FXML
    private void deleteShow() {
        Film selectedFilm = moviesListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        selectedFilm.removeFromDb();
        // since list is shared, this will be observed in all views...
        moviesListView.getItems().remove(selectedFilm); 
    }

    // ...
}
```

A similar, simpler (but complete) example is at https://github.com/james-d/SharedListView

Comment: I was testing your solution and .. That's awesome !! Thank you, that's very nice and simple. Thank you so much !